# How do you calculate the acceleration due to gravity of a massive object (black hole)

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, mass, acceleration

Is there an online calculator to find the acceleration of gravity a massive object exerts from a specific distance? I know the effects of gravity kind of just fade out with distance but I'm asking for mass-specifics.

For example, you plug in the mass of the object and the distance from the object to get the m/s^2 (and maybe even the escape velocity)???

(I'm also thinking this would be some sort of exponential graph, like "acceleration" on the y axis and "distance" on the x axis)

Comment: Not all massive objects are black holes. Newtonian gravitational acceleration is just $GM/r^2$. If you are really asking about black holes, you would have to be specific about which frame you are measuring the acceleration in. There is nothing exponential about it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Newtonian gravitational acceleration, the formula for the acceleration at a specific point, the formula is GM/(d)^2 where G is the gravitational constant which is equal to 6.67408 × 10-11 m^3 kg^-1 s^-2, M is the mass of the massive body in kg, and d is the distance from the center of mass (or just Radius + Altitude) in meters. If you don't want to calculate this yourself, a good calculator is here: [Calculator](https://planetcalc.com/1758/)

If you want to position based on time, it requires differential equations, and if you know calculus, I can expand on it if you want.